# Masm on Windows 7

Tags: assembly, windows-7, x86, masm

I want to compile and execute assembly files on windows 7.
In school they use DOS in which we are able to run MASM to compile and link and execute .asm files typed out.

Is there a way to do the same with these .asm files on windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `XP Mode` or `DosBox` and run MASM and your programs there.

Comment: DosBox works perfect !! exactly the way i intended it to work ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use MASM32, download SDK from [here](http://www.masm32.com/), and there is a nice tutorial for win32 ASM at

http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html

Alternative would be Microsoft MASM, but I haven't tried to use it on windows, here is the link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want masm for Windows 7 grab it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654

You may also need to install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MASM are you using? The recent versions of MASM (`ml.exe` and `ml64.exe`) work fine if you just start them from command line (i.e., `cmd.exe`). There's MASM executables compiled as 32-bit and a 64-bit versions, as far as I remember.